# Solve this: $\sqrt{x^2+3x+6}+\sqrt{2x^2-1}=3x+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve this:
$$\sqrt{x^2+3x+6}+\sqrt{2x^2-1}=3x+1$$
I can solve this by wolfram but I need nice solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x^2+3x+6}+\sqrt{2x^2-1}=3x+1$$

Assuming we're looking for solutions in $\mathbb{R}$, there are some conditions which $x$ has to satisfy: $x^2+3x+6\ge0\land2x^2-1\ge0$, which are obvious. Another not-so-obvious one is $3x+1\ge0$. Why? Because Square roots are always non-negative, so LHS is non-negative as sum of two non-negative numbers, so the RHS has to be such as well.

The first condition is always satisfied because discriminant is negative. The second one gives us $x\in(-\infty,-\sqrt2/2)\cup(\sqrt2/2,+\infty)$. The third one gives us $x\in(-1/3,+\infty)$. Intersection of those is $x\in(\sqrt2/2,+\infty).$

Having this condition in mind, we're free to square our equation:
$$ 2\sqrt{2x^4+6x^3+11x^2-3x-6}=6x^2+3x-4. $$

We need new conditions here, since LHS is non-negative: $6x^2+3x-4\ge0$, which gives us $x\in(-\infty,(-3-\sqrt{105})/12)\cup((-3+\sqrt{105})/12,+\infty)$, but this is already contained in $x\in(\sqrt2/2,+\infty)$, so we still have the same condition for $x$. We can now freely square:

$$ 28x^4+12x^3-83x^2-12x+40=0. $$

With a little bit of playing around, we see that we can factor this as follows:

$$ (7x^2-4x-8)(4x^2+4x-5)=0, $$

so we basically need to solve these two equations. They give us four solutions: $x=(-1\pm\sqrt6)/2\lor x=2(1\pm\sqrt{15})/7$. However, only two of these satisfy the condition:

$$ x=\frac{\sqrt6-1}2 \quad \lor \quad x=\frac{2(1+\sqrt{15})}7.$$

Note that without doing all the conditions along the way you would have to plug in four solution you've got, which can be pretty tricky at times. So it's always recommended to write conditions along the way, to save you trouble (although it seems like additional trouble at first).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Square each side.

Move all non-square terms to one side.

Square both sides again.

Solve for roots.

Be careful when checking as you'll have extra roots.

Comment: Great suggestion, and +1 for the caution!!

Comment: @amWhy: This was an example where I wanted to guide them to do it so it would sink in, but someone posted the full solution before that could happen! Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

Square both sides, and FOIL $\sqrt{x^2+3x+6}+\sqrt{2x^2-1}$

It should reduce quite nicely.